# How to apply filter on table contents in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {Doughnut} from "react-chartjs-2"

import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {fetchBeacons} from '../actions/';

const DummyDoughnutData = {
  labels: ['beacon 1 - zone a', 'beacon 2 - zone c', 'beacon 3 - zone a', 'beacon 4 - zone b', 'beacon 5 - zone b'],
  datasets: [
    {
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)',
      data: [ 30, 9, 17, 22, 11],
      backgroundColor: [
  '#063e70',
  '#107bb5',
  '#1A1C1D',
  '#666666',
  '#2F4F4F'

  ]
    }
  ],
};


// const beacons=[
//         {zone:"zone a", status: "active", _id:1},
//         {zone:"zone c", status: "active", _id:2},
//         {zone:"zone a", status: "active", _id:3},
//         {zone:"zone b", status: "active", _id:4},
//         {zone:"zone b", status: "active", _id:5},
//         {zone:"zone b", status: "active", _id:6},
//         {zone:"zone c", status: "active", _id:7}
// ];

// class BeaconZoneRow extends Component {
//     render() {
//         return (
//             <tr>
//                 <th colSpan="2">
//                     {this.props.zone}
//                 </th>
//             </tr>
//         )

//     }

// }

class BeaconRow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                 <td>{this.props.beacon.name}</td>
                <td>{JSON.stringify(this.props.beacon.status)}</td>
                <td> {this.props.beacon.zone.name} </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class BeaconList extends Component {

    // Sort = (prop) => { return (a,b) => a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop])};

    render() {
        const rows = [];

        this.props.beacons.map( beacon => {
            return rows.push(<BeaconRow beacon={beacon} key={beacon._id}/>)
        });

        return (
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Zone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )


    }
}

class BeaconDoughnutAnalysis extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <Doughnut data={DummyDoughnutData} />
                <br/>
                <center>visits</center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class BeaconListComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit(){
    this.props.router.push('/new-beacon');
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
        this.props.fetchBeacons();
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-5">
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info" onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Add Beacon</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                { this.props.beacons && this.props.beacons.length > 0 ?
                    <div className="row">
                        <BeaconList beacons={this.props.beacons}/>
                        <BeaconDoughnutAnalysis/>
                    </div> :
                    <center><h1>...Loading</h1></center>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        beacons: state.beacons
    }
}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchBeacons: fetchBeacons}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(BeaconListComponent);
```

i had fetched data from the server and i wanted to know how to filter that data in the table using react redux
the code is shown above using which table is being displayed and i wanted to filter its contents

Comment: How do you want to filter the contents, What is the current output and what do you expect to get

Comment: i am getting output as you can see in form of a table having 3 columns of name status and zone
i wanted to apply filter in that using zone and using filter when we select relevant zone its related info must be shown as of now I'm getting all the info of all the zones

Comment: brother I'm fetching the data from the api and that data was displayed in form of table
i want to apply filter in that
hope you understand now

Comment: Piyush you will be filtering data based on some key before rendering in table right and not after that

Comment: i had added the picture of my table being shown
now i want to apply filter based on zone
i wanted to know what names belong to zone 1 only
as of now its all zone 1 just imagine to be having more entries like that
as data is getting fetched from the server

Comment: just imagine to apply filter based on name so that when i type or select beacon it will show only one row as shown in the screenshot

Comment: also you know how to put maps in our page using reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are providing the zone as a prop to the BeaconList component you just need to provide a check while mapping like below

```
class BeaconList extends Component {

    // Sort = (prop) => { return (a,b) => a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop])};

    render() {
        const rows = [];
        //Assuming you are filtering based on zone and you are giving the zone you want to filter as a prop zone

        this.props.beacons.map( beacon => {
            if(beacon.zone === this.props.zone) {
              return rows.push(<BeaconRow beacon={beacon} key={beacon._id}/>)
            }
        });

        return (
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Zone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )


    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: https://ianwitherow.github.io/react-filterable-table/example/index.html

i hope you will understand now
this is how I'm saying i want to do

Comment: just forget about filter
can you tell how to open relevant information page when user click on the name in the table

Comment: Piyush I know how to get over with that filter, only thing being that I need some time to work on it. Can you tell if you have a router configured for each name. In that case you can provide a link on Name

Comment: ok will wait for the filter bro coz i need that later
also I'm using react redux so i just want to know how to push to other page
the thing is you can see the pic i shared above want to click on that name and want all info regarding that name on other screen
i had made next screen as "beacons-detail"
Also data is dynamic not static

Comment: How are you fetching the information regarding the name in the beacons-detail screen. And i suppose this is another react-component. Can ou attach that code somewhere

Comment: that's what i also wanna know bro
i just made a screen with static data only right now

Comment: I will give you an idea. What you can do is that have a dynamic route setup  like `<Route path='/location/:name' component={beacons-detail}/>`. Specify a Link on the name like <td><Link to=`"\location\${this.props.beacons.name}"`</td> And then in the beacons-detail componetn you can get teh parameter like this.props.params.name and after that you cn call and API or do whatever you want with the name. I hope it helpes

Comment: just tell brother a little in detail

Comment: Maybe you can post this as a question and someone will answer. I am a little busy right now, will try to look into it

Comment: whenever you get time just plz look at it as it was kind of main us you can say

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084457/data-fetched-from-server-is-not-getting-diplayed-in-reactjs