# Data fetched from server is not getting diplayed in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { TabContent, TabPane, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
    import classnames from 'classnames';
    let _ = require('lodash');

    import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

    import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';

    import {fetchedBeacons} from '../../actions/';

    // const beacon = {
    //     _id: 'jslg',
    //     name: 'beacon 1',
    //     description: 'something goes here',
    //     status: 'ACTIVE',
    //     manufacturer: 'EDDY',
    //     floor: '1st floor',
    //     location: 'entrance'
    // };

    // const advanceBeacon = {
    //   uuid: '452-457-854-521-125',
    //     major: '7458-458-56',
    //     minor: '7458-665',
    //     beaconType: 'bluetooth'
    // };

    const ChartData = {
      labels: ['wednesday', 'yesterday', 'today'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My First dataset',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)',
          data: [ 856, 785, 785],
          backgroundColor: [
      '#063e70',
      '#107bb5',
      '#666666'
      ]
        }
      ],
    };

    // TODO - come up with a decent name

    class InfoRow extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.beacon}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.beacon}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
    }

    class InfoRows extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
           <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.beacon.major}:</td>
                    <td>{this.props.beacon.minor}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.beacon._id}</td>
                </tr>
        )
        
      }
    }
        
    class BeaconChartAnalysis extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <Doughnut data={ChartData}/>
                    <br/>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class BeaconDetails extends Component {


        constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          activeTab: '1'
        };
      }

      toggle(tab) {
        if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
          this.setState({
            activeTab: tab
          });
        }
      }

        render() {

            const rows = [];
            let a = this.props.bcn;
            
            Object.keys(a).map(function(keyName, keyIndex){
              let b = a[keyName];
              console.log(b);
              return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} key={keyIndex}/>)
            })

            const row = [];

            // this.props.bcn.map( item => {
            //     return row.push(<InfoRows beacon={item}/>)
            // });

            return (


                <div className="col-md-6 mb-2">
                <Nav tabs>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                      className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
                      onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); }}
                    >
                      Beacon Details
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                      className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
                      onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}
                    >
                      Advanced Details
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                </Nav>
                <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                  <TabPane tabId="1">

                    <div className="col-lg-6">

                      <table className="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                          {rows}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </div>
    .
                  </TabPane>
                  
                  <TabPane tabId="2">

                    <div className="col-lg-6">
                      <table className="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                          {row}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </div>

                  </TabPane>

                </TabContent>
              </div>

            )

        }


    }

    class BeaconDetailComponent extends Component {

      componentWillMount = () => {
            this.props.fetchedBeacons(this.props.location.query.id);
        };

      
      render() {
        
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h1>Beacon Information {this.props.location.query.id}</h1></div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                    { this.props.bcn != null?
                <div className="row">
                    <BeaconDetails bcn={this.props.bcn}/>
                    <BeaconChartAnalysis />
                </div> :
                        <center><h1>...Loading</h1></center>

                }
            </div>
        )
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            bcn: state.beacons
        }

    }


    function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators({fetchedBeacons: fetchedBeacons}, dispatch);
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(BeaconDetailComponent);
```

i had provided the code snippet
what i wanted is to show the details fetched from the server
i also provided the screenshot that in console data is getting displayed but on the screen it is not
Image you can see the object being fetched from the server and its details being displayed in the console but it is not showing on the screen

Comment: In this entire code, which is the exact data that is not being  rendered and I can't see the image too.

Comment: Hope now you see the pic

Comment: Please be more explanative and tell which of InfoRow or InfoRows in not displaying and do you see any error.

Comment: InfoRow and InfoRows are separate for the two tabs being made
forget InfoRows for now
There's no error at all
No data is being displayed over here as was in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your beaconDetails compoenent you need to pass the value to the InfoRow compoent along with the key and also perform a check for null. Also you don't need a return statement in the `map` function since you are pushing object to the row array

```
 const rows = [];
        let a = this.props.bcn;
        // console.log(a);
        if(a != undefined) {
            Object.keys(a).map(function(value, keyIndex){
                 console.log(a[value]);
                 rows.push(<InfoRow beaconKey={value} beaconValue={a[value]} key={keyIndex}/>)
             })
        }
```

and in your InfoRow compoent you can display this value

```
class InfoRow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.beacon}</td>
                <td>{this.props.beaconValue}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

You can also change the beaconsDetail component to be like

```
class BeaconDetails extends Component {


        constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          activeTab: '1'
        };
      }

      toggle(tab) {
        if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
          this.setState({
            activeTab: tab
          });
        }
      }

        render() {



            const row = [];

            // this.props.bcn.map( item => {
            //     return row.push(<InfoRows beacon={item}/>)
            // });

            return (


                <div className="col-md-6 mb-2">
                <Nav tabs>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                      className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
                      onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); }}
                    >
                      Beacon Details
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                      className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
                      onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}
                    >
                      Advanced Details
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                </Nav>
                <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                  <TabPane tabId="1">

                    <div className="col-lg-6">

                      <table className="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                          {this.props.bcn && 
                            Object.keys(this.props.bcn).map(function(keyName, keyIndex){

                                return <InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName]}key={keyIndex}/>
                             })}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </div>
    .
                  </TabPane>

                  <TabPane tabId="2">

                    <div className="col-lg-6">
                      <table className="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                          {row}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </div>

                  </TabPane>

                </TabContent>
              </div>

            )

        }


    }
```

Comment: What are you seeing on screen. Does the value not come or the entire screen doesn't display

Comment: value not getting displayed on the screen
empty tabs visible only

Comment: can you attach the object `this.props.bcn` in the question. I think it has an object within itself too

Comment: Just realised there was a `return` option in Object.keys map function which should not be there. See the updated code

Comment: issue fixed as there is problem with different object types

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406383/fetch-image-from-url-and-set-as-backgraound-in-react-js