# Fetch image from URL and set as background in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to fetch the image from the URL and to display it.

I take the url as input in URL text field and when I use that in img tag it works like but when I pass or use it in td background it doesn't work

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ImageStyle extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            url: '',
            summary: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }

  render() {

    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="row px-2">Image Style Notification</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">

                <div className="px-1" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       value={this.state.title}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Image URL"
                      name="url"
                      value={this.state.url}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Summary"
                       name="summary"
                       value={this.state.summary}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div className="row px-2" >
                      <div>
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info"  onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="px-1">
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div><br />

                </div>
                <div><br />
                  <div className="mobile">
                      <table className="table table-clear width-css">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td backgroundImage: 'url(${this.state.url})'>
                            <strong>
                              {this.state.title}
                            </strong><br />
                           {this.state.summary}<br /> 
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )

  }
}

export default ImageStyle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the styles for the table and mention background image url like

```
 backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.url})`
```

```js
class ImageStyle extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            url: '',
            summary: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }

  render() {
    var styles = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.url})`
    }
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="row px-2">Image Style Notification</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">

                <div className="px-1" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       value={this.state.title}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Image URL"
                      name="url"
                      value={this.state.url}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Summary"
                       name="summary"
                       value={this.state.summary}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div className="row px-2" >
                      <div>
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info"  onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="px-1">
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div><br />

                </div>
                <div><br />
                  <div className="mobile">
                      <table className="table table-clear width-css">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style={styles}>
                            <strong>
                              {this.state.title}
                            </strong><br />
                           {this.state.summary}<br /> 
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: i tried a bit different approach
Can you help in this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408824/how-to-show-components-on-clicking-on-button-or-radio-button

Comment: if you could help in link provided
it will be a huge boost as it will be used at several other places

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408824/how-to-show-components-on-clicking-on-button-or-radio-button

Comment: Piyush, can you try this and let me know if it works

Comment: can you help in that?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455200/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-in-react-or-react-redux

Comment: Do u know how to multi select dropdown elements?
ill upload then the snippet if you have time to tell

Comment: I haven't worked on multiselect dropdowns, however I think React has  certain packages available for it