# How to Show Components on clicking on button or Radio Button

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ImageStyle extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            url: '',
            summary: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }

  render() {
 
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="row px-2">Image Style Notification</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">
  
                <div className="px-1" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       value={this.state.title}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Image URL"
                      name="url"
                      value={this.state.url}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Summary"
                       name="summary"
                       value={this.state.summary}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div className="row px-2" >
                      <div>
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info"  onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="px-1">
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div><br />

                </div>
                <div><br />
                  <div className="android">
                      <table className="table table-clear android-width">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <img src={this.state.url} alt="Notification Image" className="img-width-android"/>
                          </td>
                          <td className="img-text-css">
                            <h4><strong>
                              {this.state.title}
                            </strong></h4><br /><br /><br /><br />
                           {this.state.summary}<br /> 
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>

                    <div className="mobile">
                      <table className="table table-clear img-css">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                          <img src={this.state.url} alt="Notification Image" className="img-width-css"/>
                            </td>
                          <td className="img-text-css">
                            <h4><strong>
                              {this.state.title}
                            </strong></h4><br /><br /><br /><br />
                           {this.state.summary}<br /> 
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>


                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    
  }
}

export default ImageStyle;
```

i had made two components to show as android and IOS as per my css being added as android for android and mobile for IOS
Now what i want is to add a button or Radio Button named IOS and Android
and On Clicking the button relevant component is to be displayed only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate components for both the layouts and then create radio buttons, whole value you will keep in the state and depending on that conditionally you can render the correct component.

```
checkRadio =(e) =>{
  if(e.target.checked) {
    this.setState({layout: e.target.value});
  }
}

render() {

        return ( 
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1 className="row px-2">Image Style Notification</h1>
              <hr />
              <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">

                    <div className="px-1" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                        <div className="mb-1">
                          <input type="text"
                           className="form-control" 
                           placeholder="Title"
                           name="title"
                           value={this.state.title}
                           onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                           />
                        </div>

                        <div className="mb-1">
                          <textarea 
                          className="form-control" 
                          placeholder="Image URL"
                          name="url"
                          value={this.state.url}
                           onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                          />
                        </div>

                        <div className="mb-1">
                          <textarea
                           className="form-control" 
                           placeholder="Summary"
                           name="summary"
                           value={this.state.summary}
                           onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                           />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div className="row px-2" >
                          <div>
                            <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info"  onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                          </div>
                          <div className="px-1">
                            <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                          </div>
                        </div><br />

                    </div>
                    <div><br />
                      <input type="radio" name="layout" value="mobile" onChange={this.checkRadio}/>
                      <input type="radio" name="layout" value="android" onChange={this.checkRadio}/>
                      {(this.state.layout === "mobile")? <Android url={this.state.url} summary={this.props.summary} title={this.state.title}/>: <Mobile url={this.state.url} summary={this.props.summary} title={this.state.title}/>}





                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        )

      }


    class Android extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                 <div className="android">
                          <table className="table table-clear android-width">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <img src={this.props.url} alt="Notification Image" className="img-width-android"/>
                              </td>
                              <td className="img-text-css">
                                <h4><strong>
                                  {this.props.title}
                                </strong></h4><br /><br /><br /><br />
                               {this.props.summary}<br /> 
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
            )
        }
    }


    class Mobile extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="mobile">
                          <table className="table table-clear img-css">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                              <img src={this.props.url} alt="Notification Image" className="img-width-css"/>
                                </td>
                              <td className="img-text-css">
                                <h4><strong>
                                  {this.props.title}
                                </strong></h4><br /><br /><br /><br />
                               {this.props.summary}<br /> 
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: syntax error in this line and also there is no radio buttons in this
class Android extends Component {

Comment: Piyush, I gave an approach to solve your problem. this is not an exact solution. Also I think syntax errors are somethings that can be rectified by you. Since i have not simulated the code such errors come

Comment: i removed errors
its only showing ios part according to your snippet you provided

Comment: i got your point but didn't understand for radio buttons how to implement them and their selection

Comment: Can you try the snippet now