# How to pass data from one component to another in React or React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class BigText extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            text: '',
            summary: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }

  render() {
 
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="row animated fadeIn">
  
                <div className="px-1" style={{ width:100 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       value={this.state.title}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Text"
                      name="text"
                      value={this.state.text}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Summary"
                       name="summary"
                       value={this.state.summary}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>                      
              </div> 
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    
  }
}

export default BigText;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BigText from './bigText.js';
import InboxStyle from './inboxStyle.js';
import ImageStyle from './imageStyle.js';
import BigTextMobile from './bigText.mobile.js';
import InboxStyleMobile from './inboxStyle.mobile.js';
import ImageStyleMobile from './imageStyle.mobile.js';

class BasicNotification extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.context.router.push('/notifications');
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

    checkRadio =(e) =>{
  if(e.target.checked) {
    this.setState({layout: e.target.value});
  }
}

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="px-2">Create Notification</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">
  
                <div className="px-1 mr-2" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Text"
                      name="text"
                      />
                    </div>

                      <div>
                          <select placeholder="Logo" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option default>Select Logo</option>
                            <option>Default</option>
                            <option>Custom</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                    <div><br />

                      <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                      
                      <label className="btn btn-css btn-outline-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="layout" value="image" onChange={this.checkRadio}/>ImageStyle
                      </label>

                      <label className="btn btn-css btn-outline-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="layout" value="big" onChange={this.checkRadio}/>BigText
                      </label>

                      <label className="btn btn-css btn-outline-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="layout" value="inbox" onChange={this.checkRadio}/>InboxStyle
                      </label>
                    </div>

                      {
                          (this.state.layout === "big")?

                        <BigText/>:

                        (this.state.layout === "image")?

                        <ImageStyle/>:

                        (this.state.layout === "inbox")?

                        <InboxStyle/>:

                        null
                        }

                      <br />

                    <div className="row px-1" >
                      <div>
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info" onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="px-1">
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    </div><br />

                </div>
                <div>
                      {
                        (this.state.layout === "big")?

                        <BigTextMobile text={this.state.text} summary={this.state.summary} title={this.state.title}/>:
                        (this.state.layout === "image")?

                        <ImageStyleMobile/>:

                        (this.state.layout === "inbox")?

                        <InboxStyleMobile/>:

                        null
                      }
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    
  }
}

export default BasicNotification;
```

This is the screen i made on which I had imported three files which will be shown on clicking radio buttons.
Also there is a relevant mobile screen as well shown aside
now for example i imported as you can see BigText , it is containing the form
Now i want to print its input values in BigTextMobile Component

Comment: use redux store.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: its a long story. check out https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: without redux can be done?

Comment: yes.. there are ways. One might use Share Common Parent Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the solution you can do something like this:

```
<BigText onChange={data => {this.setState({ data })}} />
```

In the *BigText* component then you can put some data via this callback like this:

```
handleInputChange(event) {

    const data = {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    };

    this.setState(data );
    this.props.onChange(data);
}
```

And transfer this data to your *BigTextMobile* component from state:

```
<BigTextMobile data={this.state.data} ... />
```

Comment: i had BigText code snippet
can you tell now how to do?

Comment: I've edited the answer. There is one of the solutions. You also can do it via [componentWillUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

Comment: Show what you've produced eventually.

Comment: I mean could you provide the code of modified _BigText_ and _BasicNotification_ components?